# JavaScript and AJAX call 

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

As far as I know, it's possible for a client to block JavaScript in his browser. If that happens, what will happen to AJAX calls? Will they work or not?

Answer (score 5):

No, the J in AJAX stands for JavaScript - if Javascript doesn't work, then neither will AJAX.

Answer (score 4):

The AJAX call will not be executed if the user has disabled JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

AJAX is JavaScript.  No JavaScript, no AJAX.

Answer (score 2):

If javascript is disabled it will not work... You should read into Progressive Enhancement and "HIJAX"

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement

http://domscripting.com/blog/display/41

Answer (score 0):

I never bother with users without javascript, well I do bother but only to a certain extend. It might be a bit harsh but people or companies which disable javascript know that they will be missing out. Ofcourse text-only browsers should not be forgotten.